# (Audio) captureStream is not a function in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder, capturestream

I'm trying to get the *CaptureStream* of an *HTML audio element*.

```
  const sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
  var playBackStream = null

  if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
    console.log("Firefox");
    playBackStream = this.$refs.localaudio.mozCaptureStream();
  }
  else {
    console.log("Other");
    playBackStream = this.$refs.localaudio.captureStream();
  }
```

I'm using Nuxt, so that's where the $refs come from. Basically referring to something like this:

```
<audio
  id="localaudio"
  ref="localaudio"
  ...
></audio>
```

While this does work in Chrome and Firefox, it doesn't work in Safari.

> TypeError: this.$refs.localaudio.captureStream is not a function. (In
> ‘this.$refs.localaudio.captureStream()’,
> ‘this.$refs.localaudio.captureStream’ is undefined)

I read somewhere about a Safari solution like this:

```
this.$refs.localaudio.captureStream = () => playBackStream
```

But that gives me:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: S.stop is not a function. (In
> ‘S.stop()’, ‘S.stop’ is undefined)